# how to keep only rows that have highest value in certain column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble (
  ~Species, ~North, ~South, ~East, ~West,
  "a", 4, 3, 2, 3,
  "b", 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  "C", 2, 3, 3, 3,
  "D", 3, 2, 2, 2
)
```

I want to filter for species that where the highest value is e.g. North.
In this case, species A and D would be selected. Expected output would be a df with only species A and D in it.
I used a workaround like this:

```
df %>%
group_by(species) %>%
mutate(rowmean = mean(North:West) %>%
filter(North > rowmean) %>%
ungroup() %>%
select(!rowmean)
```

which seems like a lot of code for a simple task!
I cant however find a way to do this more codefriendly. Is there a (preferably tidyverse) way to perform this task in a more clean way?

Kind regards

Comment: Do you need `df %>% filter(North == max(North))`

Comment: That would select alle the species with the maximum value for 4, whilst in some cases, 3 could be the value for north and also be the highest rowvalue. Your method would not select that species. I will change my post to make this more clear.

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: Expected output would be df with only species A and D. I will add this more detailed in the post.

Comment: I think I got your point.  Can you check the solution posted below

Comment: In your code, there is rowwise mean.  that was confusing.  Are you selecting if the 'North' is greater than the rowwise mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier approach is with `max.col` in `base R`.  Select the columns that are numeric.  Get the column index of each row where the value is `max`.  Check if that is equal to 1 i.e. the first column (as we selected only from 2nd column onwards) and `subset` the rows

```
subset(df, max.col(df[-1], 'first') == 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Species North South  East  West
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a           4     3     2     3
#2 D           3     2     2     2
```

If it is based on the rowwise mean

```
subset(df, North > rowMeans(df[-1]))
```

---

Or if we prefer to use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(max.col(cur_data()[-1], 'first') == 1)
```

Similarly if it based on the rowwise mean

```
df %>% 
    filter(North > rowMeans(cur_data()[-1]))
```

Comment: Akrun why `df %>% 
  filter(across(where(is.numeric), max))` won't work. Thanks.

Comment: @TarJae the output is not logical with `max`  It works if you are using `summarise` or `mutate` to get the `max` value per group or without group for each column

Answer (score 2):

```
# base
df[df$North > rowMeans(df[-1]), ]  
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Species North South  East  West
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a           4     3     2     3
2 D           3     2     2     2
```